# Export a cross section of STL as SVG (using MeshLab)

Tags: inkscape, meshlab

I'd like to take the cross section of an STL mesh and import into Inkscape.  I have taken the cross section by doing *Filters->Quality Measures and Computation->Compute Planar Section*, but I don't see any way to export that as a 2D file.  Some forum posts elsewhere imply that this was a built-in feature of MeshLab in 2010, but there's no obvious way to do so in current versions?

Comment: While I haven't been able to solve this using MeshLab, I was able to do it in FreeCAD, by importing the .STL, and then using the Cross Sections tool from the Mesh Design workbench.   I then exported the resulting cross section geometry into a "Flattened SVG", which loaded into Inkscape and other SVG tools.

Answer (score 2):

You can export the planar section as a dxf file. Inkscape should be able to import this dxf file directly.